# Windows10でDockerを使ってGPUを使ったDeepLearning環境を構築したい

Tags: windows, docker, gpu

Windows 10 Pro
Docker for Windows(Hyper-V) version 19.03.8

上記の環境でGPUを使ったDeepLearning環境を構築したいです。
（検索してもUbuntuの記事ばかりで困っています。）

Dockerfileは以下の通りです。

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
sudo \
wget \
vim
WORKDIR /opt
RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh &&\
sh /opt/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/anaconda3 &&\
rm -f Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
ENV PATH /opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install \
keras==2.3 \
scipy==1.4.1 \
tensorflow-gpu==2.1
WORKDIR /
CMD ["jupyter","lab","--ip=0.0.0.0","--allow-root","--LabApp.token=''"]
```

エラーが以下の様に表示されました。

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
```

ドライバが認識されていないようですが、CUDA Toolkit11を以下からインストール済みです。
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

インストールされた中にドライバは入っているはずですが、どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。
また、DeepLearning用のおすすめDockerfileなどありましたら教えていただけますでしょうか。

どうぞよろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ドライバをインストールするだけでは GPU が ホスト OS から利用できるようになるだけなので、更に Docker から利用できるようにする必要があります。そして私の知る限り、2020 年 7 月現在これは Windows ではまだサポートされていない……はずです。

Linux をホスト OS とする環境では Docker から Nvidia 製 GPU を利用するのに nvidia-docker や nvidia-container-runtime が使えますが、これらは Windows に対応していません: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#is-microsoft-windows-supported

また、Hyper-V を使った場合の Windows コンテナや Linux コンテナで GPU を利用する方法も、Windows は現状サポートしていません:

> **Hyper-V-isolated Windows Container Support**
> GPU acceleration for workloads in Hyper-V-isolated Windows containers is not currently supported.
>
> **Hyper-V-isolated Linux Container Support**
> GPU acceleration for workloads in Hyper-V-isolated Linux containers is not currently supported.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/gpu-acceleration

他の将来的な方法として、WSL 2 が GPU サポートをする予定、というアナウンスがなされています: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-build-2020-summary/#wsl-gpu